# When I try to get the seekbar vue from my dialog I get a zero

Tags: android

My dialog has a seekbar on it.  I'm getting a null when I try to get the Seekbar viw that is in my dialog box.  The dialog gets drawn with the seekbar and you can move the slider back and forth

code:

```
void StartSound() {
    // custom dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sound);
    dialog.setTitle("Information");
    // bar is always null
    bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); // make
    // bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    // bar.setProgress( 10 );
    View dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok );
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    dialog.show();
}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff29245c"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- for graphic background use  android:background="@drawable/background"  --> 

    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" 
         android:max="100" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </SeekBar>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/ok"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="24px"
     android:text="OK"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="24px"
     android:layout_marginRight="24px"
     android:layout_marginTop="24px"
     android:layout_marginBottom="12px" />      

  </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting the seekbar before dialog is shown. at that time, it's view is not created hence seekbar would be null, after the oncreateview method of dialog has completed only then u can get the seekbar

Comment: Ok would I have to create a new class that dirives from dialog, then creat that class or is thee a more simple way to do this???

Comment: You can implement the onShowListener for dialog and then get seekbar on receiving that message